# SVG on an img tag has zero dimensions

Tags: html, css, svg

This is an intermittent issue that we're encountering on our site where select SVG files are 0x0. I did some little investigation and I noticed that the `figure` tag that I turned into `display: inline-block` is causing this, when I changed this to `display: block` the image starts appearing. Can anyone explain me why is that? and why is it only applicable to certain SVG files.

Here's a sample code (I'm using tailwindCSS btw):

```html
<div class="image-component">
 <figure class="relative mb-5">
  <div class="js-lightbox">
   <img src="sample.svg" class="js-zoomable">
  </div>
 </figure>
</div>
```

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.mb-5 {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.image-component figure {
    display: inline-block;
}

.js-lightbox {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.js-zoomable {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform .5s;
}

img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can the affected/unaffected SVG files be grouped by whether they have a viewBox or width/height attributes on their root element?

Comment: The affected SVG files don't have width/height indeed whereas those unaffected do.

Comment: So add width and height attributes to the affected files and your problem is solved.